# Get file name from full path in Unix

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I'm trying to get the name of a file from the full path of a parameter for a function in my bashrc. I don't know any regular expressions, so I'm kind of lost. I know I want to get the last forward slash and use everything after that, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. Then I want to store it in a variable in my function, which I'll use later.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way is to use variable substitution like

```
f1=/my/big/long/path/to/a/little/bitty/file
f2=./my/big/long/path/to/a/little/bitty/file
f3=my/big/long/path/to/a/little/bitty/file
f4=file

echo ${f1##*/}
echo ${f2##*/}
echo ${f3##*/}
echo ${f4##*/}

# This is how you get value out
filename=${f1##*/}
```

OUTPUT;

```
file
file
file
file
```

You can use `basename` but that will be slow as it will launch a new child process.

Comment: This behaves differently than basename when the path name is a directory that ends in '/'. This may or may not be a problem, depending on usage. `basename /foo/bar/` outputs **bar** whereas `x=/foo/bar/; echo ${x##*/}` outputs nothing.

Comment: if you are trying to extract file name then `/foo/bar/` should return nothing as there is no filename in the path. So logically it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use `basename $file_path`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is:

```
PATH=/my/big/long/path/to/a/little/bitty/file
FILENAME=`basename $PATH`
echo $FILENAME
```

would output 'file'

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for `basename`

Answer (score 1):

You should quote both the input to `basename` and its output in case either of them have meaningful characters like spaces in them.

```
file_basename="$(basename "$filename")"
```

Answer (score 0):

below awk command does that:

```
259> which cna_update
/vobs/cna/bin/cna_update
262> which cna_update|awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
cna_update
```